# Can't display the image in browser

Tags: php, codeigniter

`$images['result'][0]['image_path']` - here I have path of image. It is in public folder.

```
<img width="150" height="150" alt="150x150" src="<?php BASEPATH."../public/" echo $images['result'][0]['image_path'];?>" />
```

Can anyone help me to display this image?

Comment: What is `BASEPATH`?

Comment: show us your folder structure first

Comment: If BASEPATH is set then try this `<img width="150" height="150" alt="150x150" src="<?= BASEPATH."../public/". $images['result'][0]['image_path']?>" />`

Comment: Can you explain what is not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<img width="150" height="150" alt="150x150" src="<?php echo base_url('your/Folder/Structure/').$images['result'][0]['image_path'];?>" />
```

First concate your file name with path which causing the issue.
base_url() will also help you to fetch/show your image

Comment: Please highlight what you've changed and why. This helps the OP and others to learn from your answer

Comment: @Nico, Is it ok?